# Assembly - js versus ja instruction

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

So the goal is for me to write out the C code that corresponds to this assembly :

```
0:  85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
2:  78 13                   js     17 <part3+0x17>
4:  83 fe 07                cmp    $0x7,%esi
7:  77 14                   ja     1d <part3+0x1d>
9:  8d 0c f5 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rsi,8),%ecx
10: 48 d3 ff                sar    %cl,%rdi
13: 48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
16: c3                      retq   
17: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
1c: c3                      retq   
1d: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
22: c3                      retq
```

I am a little confused because the first loop testing the %esi register ends before the second loop ends.

Is the second if statement comparing %esi to 7 inside the first loop? or is this a if , else if situation??

Comment: I don't see a loop anywhere. Yeah, it's `if`/`else if`. Of course all it does is return stuff, you don't need the `else`.

Comment: `if (esi < 0 || esi > 7) return 0; return (int64_t)rdi >> (8*esi);`?

Comment: Fun fact: since both cases do the same (`return 0`), and `ja` includes `js`, you can just ignore the `js`.

Comment: @Jester my bad - incorrect terminology, ill edit it, but thanks for the help

Comment: @EOF thanks! this was exactly the case!

Comment: @Jester I don't think the `js` can be ignored; is it possible you've missed the `test %esi, %esi` that's setting the flags for the `js` ?

Comment: @Tommylee2k it can be ignored because if the `js` triggers, the `ja` triggers too, and they both do the same thing. Note that `ja` is unsigned, so the negative numbers are above `7`.

Comment: @Jester ah, i switched my head after i heard "C" you're completely right :-) shame on me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sum up, what's already been said

```
0:  85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
2:  78 13                   js     17 <part3+0x17>
```

this is " if (esi < 0) goto 17; "

```
4:  83 fe 07                cmp    $0x7,%esi
7:  77 14                   ja     1d <part3+0x1d>
```

this is " if (esi >7) goto 1d; "

```
9:  8d 0c f5 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rsi,8),%ecx
```

"cx = 8*rsi" // not that obvious it's "just" a multiplication)

```
10: 48 d3 ff                sar    %cl,%rdi
```

rdi >> cl;   // not cx, but cx is safe to be <= 7*8, so that's the same
    13: 48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
    16: c3                      retq

return rdi;

```
17: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
1c: c3                      retq
```

17: "return 0"

```
1d: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
22: c3                      retq
```

1d: another "return 0"

so the C-Code is:

```
{
    if (esi < 0) return 0;
    if (esi > 7) return 0;
    return rdi >> ( 8 * rsi );
}
```

PS: the 2 "return 0" (17 and 1d) give a clear indication that, in the C-code, the two `if`s were NOT combined into one
PSS: the C Code was obviously **not** compiled with optimization :P