# Understanding lea and assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I was hoping someone could validate my understanding of the following assembly code:

```
test %esi,%esi
js 17 <build+0x17>
cmp $0x8,%esi
ja 1d <build+0x1d>
lea (&rsi,2),%ecx
shl $0x2,%rdi
mov %rdi,%rax
retq
mov $0x0,%eax //17
retq
mov $0x0,%eax //1d
retq
```

Here's what I think the code does:

- If esi&esi is negative return item at address 0
- If esi is above 8, return item at address 0
- Else store address of rsi *2 into ecx
- Then right shift rdi right by 2 bits
- Copy rdi to rax and return it

Comment: Return 0, not return anything at address 0

Comment: Is the rest of it accurate?

Comment: The line `lea (&rsi,8),%ecx` should probably be written `lea (,%rsi,8),%ecx` and means `ECX=RSI*8` and not 'address of rsi`. The rest looks good.

Comment: And of course _"If esi&esi is negative"_ == _"If esi is negative"_

Comment: `esi & esi == esi`

Comment: same asm code is discussed there: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379900/assembly-js-versus-ja-instruction]

Comment: `lea` is just a shift-and-add instruction.  It just happens to use the effective-address encoding / syntax to express the shifting and adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the code does:

```
if (esi >= 0 && esi <= 7) {
    return rdi >> (esi * 8);   // Note: arithmetic shift; preserves sign
}
return 0;
```

So `esi` specifies the number of bytes (0..7) to shift out on the right from `rdi`. Since an arithmetic shift is used, the original sign of `rdi` is preserved.

For example:

```
Input:
  rdi = 0xFC00AABB12345678
  esi = 2

Output:
  rax = 0xFFFFFC00AABB1234
```